# MapCircle not updating on center or radius change

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, xcode15, ios17

Related to [MapCircle not updating on center or radius change](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733868?login=true).
Using Xcode 15.0 beta 4
I have `MapCoordinate` struct:

```
private struct MapCoordinate: Equatable {
        let location: Location
        let latitude: Double
        let longitude: Double
        
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        }
        
        init?(location: Location) {
            guard let latitude = location.latitude,
                  let longitude = location.longitude else {
                return nil
            }
            
            self.location = location
            self.latitude = latitude
            self.longitude = longitude
        }
    }
```

`mapCoordinate` and `radius` state variables:

```
    @State private var mapCoordinate: MapCoordinate?
    @State private var radius: CLLocationDistance
```

And a `mapView`:

```
    @ViewBuilder var mapView: some View {
        Map {
            if let mapCoordinate {
                let annotationTitle = radius.toMeasurement(unit: .meters, convertedTo: .kilometers)
                Annotation(annotationTitle, coordinate: mapCoordinate.coordinate) {
                    Image(systemImage: .mapPinEllipse)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
                
                MapCircle(center: mapCoordinate.coordinate, radius: radius)
                    .foregroundStyle(.teal.opacity(circleOpacity))
                    .stroke(.teal, lineWidth: circleStrokeLineWidth)
            }
        }
        .mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: mapCoordinate)
    }
```

My goal is to let user choose a radius around his location.
When updating `mapCoordinate` the `Annotation` will animate correctly to the new coordinates, but the `MapCircle` will not update or change scale for neither `mapCoordinate` or `radius` changes.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this issue was solved on beta 5